# Use two datepicker controls to specify a start and end date?

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, xaml, .net-4.0

I am trying to use two DatePicker controls to specify a start and end date within a specified range, whilst also limiting the selections so that the start date is before the end date and the end date is after the start date.

So I have tried this XAML:

```
<GroupBox Grid.Row="1" Header="Run Length">
            <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                <DockPanel VerticalAlignment="Top">
                    <Label DockPanel.Dock="Left">Start Date</Label>
                    <DatePicker DockPanel.Dock="Right" Height="25" SelectedDate="{Binding Path=RunStartDate, ValidatesOnDataErrors=True, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" DisplayDateStart="{Binding Path=MinDate, Mode=OneWay, NotifyOnSourceUpdated=True}" DisplayDateEnd="{Binding Path=RunEndDate, Mode=OneWay, NotifyOnSourceUpdated=True}"></DatePicker>
                </DockPanel>
                <DockPanel VerticalAlignment="Top">
                    <Label DockPanel.Dock="Left">End Date</Label>
                    <DatePicker DockPanel.Dock="Right" Height="25" SelectedDate="{Binding Path=RunEndDate, ValidatesOnDataErrors=True, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" DisplayDateStart="{Binding Path=RunStartDate, Mode=OneWay, NotifyOnSourceUpdated=True}" DisplayDateEnd="{Binding Path=MaxDate, Mode=OneWay, NotifyOnSourceUpdated=True}"></DatePicker>
                </DockPanel>
            </StackPanel>
        </GroupBox>
```

However when the values of 'MinDate' and 'MaxDate' change, the DatePickers do not? Can anyone explain why?

Thanks,
Alex.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Make sure `MinDate` and `MaxDate` are public properties which implement `INotifyPropertyChanged`.

Here is a [MSDN example](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms743695.aspx) to help you out.

Answer (score 3):

Make sure your MinDate and MaxDate are Dependency Properties or implement INotifyPropertyChanged.

Answer (score 1):

1. Make sure MinDate and MaxDate are implementing INotifyPropertyChanged interface.
2. Check DataContext has assigned or not.